# Textbox watermark extender not visible in design view

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using visual studio 2010 and ajax control toolkit 4 is added .

When I drag textbox watermark extender in design view its not added. Please help me. I am new to asp.net 2010

thankx in advance

madhu

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the whether the below line is added or not in .aspx file:-
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
Also check in references whether AjaxToolkit.dll is reflected or not.
Also make sure that u r using Toolscriptmanager below the form tag as follows:-